# How do i fix axios 500 internal server error on delete request?

Tags: reactjs, mern

hello everyone please i am still stuck on this problem][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaR6P.png)

```
Import  { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const ConfirmBooking = () => {
  //track state
  const [data,setData] = useState([])

  const Style  =  {
   color: 'rgb(97, 113, 154)',
   padding: '5px'

  }

//GET data
 useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:5000/api/bookings')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      setData(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
 }, [])
  //DELETE data
 const deleteHandler =(id) =>{
    axios
       .delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/bookings/${id}`)
       .then(res => {
        console.log('deleted',res)
        setData(res.data)
       })
       .catch(error =>{
        console.log(error)
       })
    }

 if(!data?.length) return <div>loading...</div>

return (
  <div className='bookings'>
    <h4 style={Style}>Name:{" "}{data.at(-1).name}</h4> 
    <h4 style={Style} >Service:{" "}{data.at(-1).service}</h4>
    <h4 style={Style} >Date:{" "}{data.at(-1).date}</h4>
    <h4 style={Style} >Cost:{" "}{data.at(-1).cost}</h4><br></br>
    <button  >Edit</button>
    <button onClick={ () => deleteHandler(data.at(-1).id)} >Delete</button>
  </div>
 )
  
  }
  
export default ConfirmBooking;
```

[As seen above, the delete handler function isn't working. Please how do I make it work, still new in programming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txuGd.png)? I KEEP GETTING THIS ERROR IN THE CONSOLE AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500',.Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... At a glance it would appear that you're invoking your `deleteHandler` function *immediately* upon rendering the component, rather than in response to the user clicking.  Wrap it in a function: `onClick={() => deleteHandler(...)}`

Comment: 500 means your server went down after the request have you checked the server logs?

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot, the deleteHandler method accepts the event as an argument, to pass the data.at(-1).name you need to call it like so

```
onClick={() => deleteHandler(data.at(-1).name}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.I have edited the post, and I tried your solution but got the same error in the console

Comment: I agree with the comment above, 500 error is likely that your server is not running or a failure occurred, can you include a log of what the server error is from the server side? It should tell you where the failure is occurring and why, also check that you're hitting the correct API, something simple as a / could throw it off

Comment: thanks, the problem is that it is not throwing any error on the server side. The catch block is not executing